# Calculating AUC for Unsupervised LOF in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, anomaly-detection

I'm trying to calculate `ROCAUC` after running fit_predict for a LOF model on a dataset.

I am using `sklearn` for the LOF implementation. I recognize I can get scores back by calling `model.negative_outlier_factor_` but I am not sure how to transform these scores into probabilities to do an `AUC` calculation

This is for comparison to another model. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to convert the model.negative_outlier_factor_ into probabilities for ROC_AUC calculation, just a relative score will be good enough.

```
samples = [[0., 0., 0.], [0., .5, 0.], [1., 1., .5]]

from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor
lof = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=3,novelty=True)
lof.fit(samples) 
roc_auc(1/lof.score_samples(X_test),y_test)
```

Comment: This may sound stupid, but where is the score_samples function? I see it in the documentation, but when I call after training, calling clf.score_samples tells me the method score_samples doesn't exist.

Comment: you have give novelty as True for score_samples option to be enabled